# gevent/libevent.h:9:19: fatal error: event.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, virtualenv

I was trying to work on Pyladies website on my local folder. I cloned the repo, (https://github.com/pyladies/pyladies) ! and created the virtual environment. However when I do the pip install -r requirements, I am getting this error

```
Installing collected packages: gevent, greenlet
Running setup.py install for gevent
building 'gevent.core' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/local/include -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c gevent/core.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/gevent/core.o
In file included from gevent/core.c:253:0:
gevent/libevent.h:9:19: fatal error: event.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
Complete output from command /home/akoppad/virt/pyladies/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/akoppad/virt/pyladies/build/gevent/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-4MSIGy-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/akoppad/virt/pyladies/include/site/python2.7:
running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

building 'gevent.core' extension

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/local/include -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c gevent/core.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/gevent/core.o

In file included from gevent/core.c:253:0:

gevent/libevent.h:9:19: fatal error: event.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /home/akoppad/virt/pyladies/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/akoppad/virt/pyladies/build/gevent/setup.py';   exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-4MSIGy-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/akoppad/virt/pyladies/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/akoppad/virt/pyladies/build/gevent
Storing complete log in /home/akoppad/.pip/pip.log.
```

I tried doing this, 
    sudo port install libevent
    CFLAGS="-I /opt/local/include -L /opt/local/lib" pip install gevent

It says port command not found.

I am not sure how to proceed with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I had the same problem and just as the other answer suggested I had to install "libevent". It's apparently not called "libevent-devel" anymore (apt-get couldn't find it) but doing:

```
    $ apt-cache search libevent
```

listed a bunch of available packages.

```
    $ apt-get install libevent-dev
```

worked for me.

Comment: Perfect! It simply rocked :)

Comment: This solution should be marked as correct not the other one

Answer (score 11):

I think you just forget to install the "libevent" in the environment. If you are on a OSX machine, please try to install brew here http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/ and use brew install libevent to install the dependency. If you are on an ubuntu machine, you can try apt-get to install the corresponding library.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was trying to do sudo apt-get install libevent-devel inside the virtual environment. Hence the error. I installed it normally outside the virtual environment and it installed in a normal manner. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue while trying to

```
pip install Flask-Sockets
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
```

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

```
yum install libevent-*
```

This command works for me because I am on centos.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error on MacOS 10.10.1 (Yosemite) running pip install. The solution for me was to add the path to libevent which pip was missing. These are C files, and CFLAGS and DFLAGS are bash environment variables that let pip know where to find these files. On my system, libevent is found at /usr/local/include/event2.

```
$ CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include/event2 DFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib pip install -r requires.txt
```